# Best way to Create a CSV, Compress it and Attatch with Email

Tags: python, django, email, csv

I have a Question, I am searching for a best way to perform following tasks.

- Create In-Memory csv file
- Compress it (Gizip, or Zip)
- Attach it with the email

I am having hard time find out the exact solution which i am looking for.

here is my code.

### code

```
prospects = Customer.objects.filter(state_id=2)
csvfile = StringIO.StringIO()
writer = UnicodeWriter(csvfile, encoding='utf-8')
writer.writerow(["Name", "Email"])
for prospect in prospects:
    writer.writerow(
        [prospect.name, prospect.email]
    )
csvobj = csvfile.getvalue() # not sure about it.
```

### Code Part 2

```
g = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=csvobj)
g.close()
```

### Code Part 3

```
  msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            subject="Innovation",
            body="text_context",
            from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
            to=["bac@gmail.com"]
        )
  msg.attach("z.gzip",g, 'application/zip')
  msg.send(True)
```

### Error

```
TypeError: 'GzipFile' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
import StringIO
import tablib

headers = ["name", "Email"]
values = Customer.objects.filter(state_id=2).values_list(‘name’, ‘email’)
data = tablib.Dataset(*values, headers=headers)

csvfile = StringIO.StringIO()
csvfile.write(data.csv)

gzipped = gzip.GzipFile(mode='wb', fileobj=csvfile.getvalue())
gzipped.close()

# msg stuff...
msg.attach("z.gzip", gzipped, 'application/zip')
```

Works fine for me, do you still get an error if you try that?

Comment: Small optimisation would be using `cStringIO` instead of `StringIO`.

Comment: @Blackeagle52: Unless you want to support unicode strings.